# Image format mismatch for watershed segmentation in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, watershed

I'm trying to implement a watershed segmentation using Java wrapper for OpenCV.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
public void watershedSegmentation(Mat image)
    {
        Mat target =  new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, target, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2RGB);

        //Conversion to 8UC1 grayscale image
        Mat grayScale = new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_64FC1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayScale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);


        //Otsu's Threshold, applied to the grayscale image
        Imgproc.threshold(grayScale, grayScale, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

        //constructing a 3x3 kernel for morphological opening
        Mat openingKernel = Mat.ones(3,3, CvType.CV_8U);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(grayScale, grayScale, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, openingKernel, new Point(-1,-1), 3);

        //dilation operation for extracting the background
        Imgproc.dilate(grayScale, grayScale, openingKernel, new Point(-1,-1), 1);


        Imgproc.watershed(target, grayScale);

    }
```

Right at the point where I invoke 'watershed', I see an error which reads:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Only 32-bit, 1-channel output images are supported) in cvWatershed, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\segmentation.cpp, line 151
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\segmentation.cpp:151: error: (-210) Only 32-bit, 1-channel output images are supported in function cvWatershed
]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.watershed_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.watershed(Imgproc.java:9732)
    at segmentation.Segmentation.watershedSegmentation(Segmentation.java:60)
    at segmentation.Segmentation.main(Segmentation.java:29)
```

I get it, OpenCV is hunting for a 32-bit 1-channel file as the output.

I have tried every possible combination:

- CvType.CV_32FC1,
- CvType.CV_32F,
- CvType.CV_32S,
- CvType.CV_32SC1,
- CvType.CV_8UC1,
- CvType.CV_16UC1

... all of them.

The error is resilient. It refuses to go away.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Your grayscale matrix is most probably of type CV_8UC1 even if you created it using CV_64F flag, after going through `Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayScale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);`

`watershed` expects the second matrix parameter to be a CV_32F matrix, filled with initial seeds for the regions, see [the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=watershed#void%20watershed%28InputArray%20image,%20InputOutputArray%20markers%29).

[edit] 
Following the comments, if you just want watershed to run, you can do something like:

```
Mat seeds = new Mat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CvType.CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  // initialize 10 random seeds
  seeds.at<float>(rand()%image.rows, rand()%image.cols) = i; // translate that into the Java interface
}
Imgproc.watershed(target, seeds);
```

Comment: Ok, so you suspect the cvtColor(...) is changing the image type to CV_8UC1 ? What could be a possible workaround (since I need the grayscaling there) ?

Comment: I can confirm you're right. I checked grayScale.depth() before and after cvtColor(). It is changing to one channel. But I'm yet to find a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? The second matrix is an initialiser (gives region seeds) for the watershed algorithm. Let me give it a guess: convert to grayscale, use otsu + morpho to generate some connected components, this is what you do. Then label those connected components, put them in a matrix of CV_32F and call watershed with that.

Comment: Yeh, I've reserved CCL for later. I've got my own code for that, which I'll plug into this code block later. Right now I'm not much concerned if the watershed returns a good output or not, I just want to get it up and running.

Comment: Alright, but for the watershed to work, you need to initialize it with some seeds. Is it not the purpose of thresholding+opening in your code?

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right. For now... all seeds set to 1 will suffice.

Comment: But if you want your connected components to be in different seeds, you need to set them to different values

Comment: Yes. But now I just want the code to run, I don't care what happens to segmentation. I've implemented my own version of a simple CCL, without using openCV. I will test that here. But first, I just want this thing to run without crashing. I'll check the segmentation later, no problem if no segmentation happens at all!

Comment: Sorry for interrupt, but i need a complete code in java-opencv of watershed implementation. I tried a lot, but not get output. Thanks in advance